# Where Condition on relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to fetch users based on their role_id from database through ajax. I did this using below code.

```
        $queryModel->whereHas('roles',function ($query) use ($role_id) {
           $query->where("role_id",$role_id);
        });
```

But on live server I have more than 40,000 users so it takes a lot of time to fetch data. This is because of using whereHas().I tried using where but it did not work.
is there any solution which makes search fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `Role` model which also have a relation with `User` model you can try something like this;

```
$role = Role::findOrFail($role_id);
$users = $role->users; // got all users which have that specific role
// or you can use query builder
$users = $role->users()->where('name', 'like', 'U%')->get();
```

As a result you don't need to check all users to find which of them have a specific role. You start with role and access it's users.

Comment: it is not working the way it should. It gets all the user of that role but I want only the ones searched by user. for example if I search for "Cut" it should give me the one(s) whose name start with "cut" like cutting company etc

Comment: If you use  `$role->users()->where('name', 'like', 'U%')->get();` it creates a query builder with `$role->users()` and add where clause on it, it runs the result query. So it doesn't fetch all users on that role. But if you directly use `$role->users` it fetches them all. You need to use it with parentheses.